# Object creation of UIAutomator or Appium

Tags: appium, android-uiautomator

I need to record all Xpaths/resource in a when I click on an element in UIAutomator or Appium Inspector session. To do the above I need to create an Object of UIAutomator/Appium in my code so that I can run commands such as `UIAutomator.recordElement()` or along those lines to record the Xpaths which I clicked in a file.

I have used both Appium and UIAutomator to get the Xpaths but I have to manually copy and paste those Xpaths/resourceID from the interface to my code.

Example of Xpath :

```
//android.widget.LinearLayout[@content-desc=\"Numbers and basic operations\"]/android.view.ViewGroup[1]/android.widget.Button[9]"
```

The above path was obtained from Appium while using the Calculator App in an Android Emulator via manual copy and paste.
I need to get it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In Appium Desktop there is ["Start Recording" button](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/blob/master/README.md#the-recorder)

[image]

which automatically captures the actions you perform in the mobile application or website and translates it into the code in variety of programming languages/frameworks

[image]

You might also want to try out [Appium Studio](https://experitest.com/mobile-test-automation/appium-studio/) which makes the processes of managing devices/emulators, recording and tests execution much easier.